# How do I stop a view from taking the screen's width and overlapping other components in React Native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build a react native Note posting application where a user will press a button and a new note will be added to the screen. Each note has a title and a detail. For now, they are being incremented. So first time the user presses the button, a component with 'title 1' and 'detail 1' will be posted as a simple colored square. The problem now is, I want to be able to have a scroll-able view on the whole screen, and at the same time have a button locked on the screen on the bottom right corner that does not move even when we are scrolling through the application.

An example of that is the Gmail app's Button for sending an email.
[Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BKqy.jpg)

And this is my App, and the red Touchable opacity "Add Note!" adds components.

Before adding notes :

[Before adding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paRk6.jpg)

After adding notes:

[After adding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L58Eq.jpg)

How do I place the "Add Note!" button at the right lower corner of the screen and lock it so that it doesn't move even when the components in FlatList Surpasses the screen.

My Code :`

```
const IndexScreen = () => {
    const {state, addNote } = useContext(Context);
    return <View style={styles.Container}>
      <ScrollView>
          <FlatList
            data={state}
            keyExtractor={Note => Note.title}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
              return (item.note)
            }}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Note} onPress={addNote}>
            <Text>Add Note!</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    Container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        borderWidth : 2,
        borderColor: 'black',
    },
    Note: {
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      borderWidth : 2,
      borderColor: 'yellow',
      alignSelf: 'flex-end',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      flex: 1

    }
  });
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try react-native-action-button. It will look great and at the same time your issue will be resolved. Here is the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-action-button).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but you can try setting the `position: absolute` and then setting `right` and `bottom` properties too, so it then becomes fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I place the "Add Note!" button at the right lower corner of the
>   screen and lock it so that it doesn't move even when the components in
>   FlatList Surpasses the screen

You can use `absolute` positioning. Like this:

```
Note: {
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  borderWidth : 2,
  borderColor: 'yellow',
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  position: "absolute",
  bottom: 0,
  right: 0
}
```

I added `position`, `left` and `right` properties.

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-floating-action` should do the trick. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-floating-action